# Laravel doesn't show the image if it's concatenated with other image

Tags: php, laravel-5

Laravel doesn't show the image if it's concatenated with another image. I'm using Laravel 5.6. Any solution?

```
<div class="card-img mt-2 mb-2">
  <img src=" {{URL::to('images/' . $value->file)}}" class="position-static  img-fluid rounded" height="300px" width="200px"  alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Look at the source in the browser. Does the path show, and is it correct?

Comment: the path is working , but the other one ($value->file) is not working ,iit show only one in same time i don't know why

Comment: Remove the space before `{{URL ...}}`?

Comment: You need to check the value of both. This is why I suggested seeing what the echoed value was in the browser source, to make sure the path looks correct.

Comment: same , both are correct , if i the code is like this ($value->file) only its works , or if ithe code is (URL::to('images/')) its works , if i concatenate them its doesn't work

Comment: I'm confused now, does it work or does it not? Does `{{URL::to('images/' . $value->file)}}` generate the correct path to the file? What does it look like? Does that file exist? Have you tried to remove the space before `{{URL ...}}` as suggested?

Comment: I removed the space  and its not working , this{{ (($value->file) )]] work fine , and this {{URL::to('images/')}} also work , but this {{URL::to('images/' . $value->file)}} only show the image from (/images) and the other($value->file)  not